# error when try to connect my router/switch to putty/teraterm

Tags: switch, router

I get the following error when I try to connect to my router or switch. i checked it with both putty and tera term but the error remains the same[image]

Comment: Your baud rate is incorrect.

Comment: you need to set bit rate 9600 or appropriate as per serial cable/serial port/converter bit rating.